# Nesting div in HTMLHelper

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to center some content in an animated button I created. In essence, I'm trying to implement the HTML below using HTMLActionLink.

Is it possible to nest a div inside of the link like above whilst using HTMLActionLink?

Is it possible to nest anything inside of any HTMLHelper?

And here is the style-sheet if at all useful:

```css
.linkbox-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 2px auto;
}

.linkbox-button-bl,
.linkbox-button-rd {
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0.7s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.linkbox-button-content {
  margin-top: 25%;
}

.linkbox-button:hover .linkbox-button-rd,
.linkbox-button:hover .linkbox-button-bl {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkbox-button" style="background-image:url(../../Images/General/coach.png)">
  <a href="#" class="linkbox-button-bl">
    <div class="linkbox-button-content">
      <p> hello </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I mean you could also tell me how to center the content inside of the link without the use of an additional div D:. This is the only thing I could come up with that doesn't sacrifice the entirety of the button being a link.

I haven't been able to find any resources indicating anything of the like so i apologize if this is a duplicate.

Comment: No its not possible. The `@Html.ActionLink()` method generates a `<a>` element only. (and since you not even generating a link to redirect, there would be no point using it anyway)

Comment: Use `MvcHtmlString` method with `MvcHtmlString.Create()` to create multiple HTML elements in a custom HTML helper, since `ActionLink` as its stated just used to render single anchor element. Read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) to find out your needs.

Comment: @StephenMuecke There's somewhere I need to link I've just used a generic for the purposes of the question

Comment: You could create you own extension method if its something you use regularly and/or across multiple projects, but it might be just as easy to use `<a href="@Url.Action(...)" ... >` if your just wanting to ensure that the url's are correctly generated

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys! I'll need to weigh the two options.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Where can I find the default HTMLHelpers? I want to gauge whether or not I'll be able to create the extension method that I need

Comment: Here you can find all HTML helpers (and their overloads): [System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.108).aspx). Extension methods can involve standard helpers to generate HTML elements.

Comment: Just a small advice: create your own custom extension method if you intend to reuse it in multiple places. If not, don't bother. Razor can accomodate plain html without problems. Also, don't use div inside an anchor. The W3C doesn't recommend it and, from what I see in the  in the css code, a simple span tag will suffice.

Comment: @IonutUngureanu Where would you place the span tag? The nested div? I didn't really feel comfortable creating a div inside the link tbh but I didn't have a better solution.

Comment: I meant that you use <span> instead of <div>. For example: `<a href="#" class="linkbox-button-bl"><span class="linkbox-button-content">hello</span></a>`